# Get variable out from function which is calling export.modules node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the file users.js I want to get `code` out of `randomCode()` to assign to the `result` and use it in whole endpoint `'/login'`.

**randomCode.js**

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const randomCode = (callback) =>{
    crypto.randomInt(100000, 999999, (err, n) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(n);
    });
}
    
module.exports = randomCode
```

**users.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const randomCode = require('../controllers/randomCode')


router.get('/login', async (req, res, next)=>{
    try{
//-----------------------------------------------------
        randomCode((code) => {
          console.log(code,'code')
        })
//-----------------------------------------------------
        return res.send('ok')
    }
    catch(error){
        res.send(error)
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I tried to use `await` but whithout results.

```
router.get('/login', async (req, res, next)=>{
    try{
//------------------------------------------------------
        const result = await randomCode((code) => {
          console.log(code,'code')
        })
        console.log(result)
//------------------------------------------------------
        return res.send('ok')
    }
    catch(error){
        res.send(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: Why don't you just use randomCode as a helper method instead of a controller? crypto.randomInt won't ever throw an error, so you can skip the callback, just returning the code and using it like this:

const code = randomCode();

However, I don't really see a problem with your code, what is the console printing?

Comment: The reason why I insert ```randomCode()``` in controller is: to find out :) I faced before with this kind of "problem" but usually I skipped it and moved function from controller to other location.

Comment: That's completely fair, good on you! I tried replicating that in a javascript file, and both functions seems to be working ok, so the problem must be somewhere else. What is the console.log printing your case?

Comment: Example app listening at http://localhost:8000--------
Database connected.------
undefined--------
568350 code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be different approaches (especially as [`crypto.randomInt`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptorandomintmin-max-callback) could be
called synchronously), but I understand you are specifically interested in how
to get a value from an asynchronous function, so I'll answer that:

```
const randomCode = function(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.randomInt(100000, 999999, (err, n) => {
      if( err ){
        reject( err );
      } else {
        resolve( n );
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```
router.get('/login', async (req, res, next)=>{
  try{
    const code = await randomCode();
    console.log(code)
    return res.send('ok')
  }
  catch(error){
    res.send(error)
  }
})
```

In cases where you can not change the `randomCode()` function for some reason, you need to wrap it into a Promise, like:

```
const randomCodePromise = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        randomCode((code) => {
            resolve( code );
        })
    });
}
```

(and obviously then use `await randomCodePromise()` instead of `await randomCode()`)